# Angular-cli not generating typescript files with --dev option

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

Using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.14, node: 6.6.0, os: win32 x64. Of course, this is the webpack version of angular-cli.  I'm able to use ng build.  The ng build output gives this webpack Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.22.

I'm wondering why the TypeScript files don't get bundled when I run ng build --dev. I get js files and sourcemaps (which unfortunately Chrome chokes on - I get Failed to parse SourceMap). I would think for a DEV deploy, in addition to source maps, I would get the typescript files I developed. Is there some documentation on the options to be used with ng build?

Answer (score 1):

See @vt5491's detailed answer here:

- [Typescript files not showing in Angular 2 CLI project using chrome web developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584122/typescript-files-not-showing-in-angular-2-cli-project-using-chrome-web-developer/37627935#37627935)

---

Also, I beleive it's just `ng b -dev` with one `-`. See `ng help` here:

```
...

ng build <options...>
  Builds your app and places it into the output path (dist/ by default).
  aliases: b
  --target (String) (Default: development)
    aliases: -t <value>, -dev (--target=development), -prod (--target=production)

...
```

---

We have a similar issue with styles being all put into `index.html`'s `<style>` tags. See:

- [How to Source Map Angular CLI css files in Chrome Dev Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162982/how-to-source-map-angular-cli-css-files-in-chrome-dev-tools)