# Angular-CLI sass Source Map

Tags: angular, sass, angular-cli, scss-lint

ng serve compiles my app, but when I'm inspecting the html, the source of the CSS seems to be (style)...(/style).
Does anybody knows how to configure sass source map via Angular-CLI ?

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/stevebelovarich/compiling-sass-postcss-with-angular-cli-du107x931

Comment: @anshuVersatile that post is now out of date (according to the author in the post comments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Source Map Angular CLI css files in Chrome Dev Tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162982/how-to-source-map-angular-cli-css-files-in-chrome-dev-tools)

Answer (score 9):

When you type ng serve by default angular cli doesn't include sourcemaps files for css files but you can include it by typing this command

```
ng serve -sm -ec
```

or

```
ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss
```

I use Angular Cli -v 1.0.3, and More information - [Angular CLI special cases](https://medium.com/@IMM9O/angular-cli-some-special-cases-f48059fb33e5)

Perhaps, its help you.

Comment: on AngularCLI 1.3.0  `ng serve -sm -ec` **works**, but `ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss` doesn't.

Comment: Hi, ShinDarth. Very strange. I updated AngularCLI 1.3.2 and all works.

Comment: It's not camel case. It's --extract-css

Comment: @phip1611 : there are multiple aliases :  --extract-css (Boolean) Extract css from global styles onto css files instead of js ones.
    aliases: -ec, --extractCss

Comment: Per comment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40224003/3232832, seems as of Dec 2018, NG CLI still cannot properly link to the exact / original SCSS line.  However, with the method in this answer, it can at least show you the right line of CSS, which can then be searched for.